# How to add child routes without rendering parent route content in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this routes configuration.

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Redirect to="/tab" />
  </Route>
  {loading ? (
    <Loader style={{ margin: 100 }} />
  ) : (
    <>
      <Route exact path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />
      <Route exact path="/termsofuse" component={TermsOfUse} />
      <Route exact path="/tab" component={Tab} />
      <Route exact path="/config" component={TabConfig} />
    </>
  )}
</Router>
```

I would like to add children routes `"/tab/organizer"` and `"tab/candidate"`.
I'm new to react and I would like to know how can I render these two routes without rendering `"/tab"` content?
I'm using `react-router-dom@5`

Comment: So you want to add descendent routes to `"/tab"` and you *don't* want the `Tab` component to rerender? Or you want to add sibling routes that render different content? Can you edit your post to include all relevant code, specifically the `Tab` component, and the new routes and their components? See [mcve].

Comment: Yes I'm hesitating between descendant route or as @dan suggessed using exact prefix.

I won't render tab component. but I don't know if I should write the `<Route>` inside tab component or again as @dan suggessed

Comment: It basically depends on if you want to render the `Tab` component in addition to the components rendered on the descendent routes, or if you want them all to render independently. I can share examples if you like.

Comment: In this case I would render them independently. so I think I should use @Dan example ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using exact paths, it's as simple as adding your new route:

```
<Route exact path="/tab" component={Tab} />    
<Route path="/tab/organizer" component={Organizer} />
<Route path="/tab/candidate" component={Candidate} />
```

It won't render the Tab component as long as exact is set.

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: Thank you for your second contribution.
should I instead use `<Switch>` is it better ?

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, you're right, a switch would be easier to read

Answer (score 0):

You can render 3 independent "tab" routes. I suggest rendering the routes within the `Switch` component and ensure the routes are ordered in inverse order of specificity, i.e. from ***more*** specific to ***less*** specific. Ordering the routes correctly nearly eliminates the need for the `exact` prop to disambiguate the path matching.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Redirect to="/tab" />
  </Route>
  {loading ? (
    <Loader style={{ margin: 100 }} />
  ) : (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />
      <Route path="/termsofuse" component={TermsOfUse} />
      <Route path="/tab/candidate" component={Candidate} />
      <Route path="/tab/organizer" component={Organizer} />
      <Route path="/tab" component={Tab} />
      <Route path="/config" component={TabConfig} />
    </Switch>
  )}
</Router>
```

Alternatively you could create a "layout" component that renders on `"/tab"` and then renders descendent routes. The benefit here is that you can move *all* of the "tab" routes at once by just updating the path of its parent route.

Example:

```
import { Route, Switch, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

const TabLayout = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/candidate`} component={Candidate} />
      <Route path={`${path}/organizer`} component={Organizer} />
      <Route path={path} component={Tab} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

...

```
<Router>
  <Route exact path="/">
    <Redirect to="/tab" />
  </Route>
  {loading ? (
    <Loader style={{ margin: 100 }} />
  ) : (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />
      <Route path="/termsofuse" component={TermsOfUse} />
      <Route path="/tab" component={TabLayout} />
      <Route path="/config" component={TabConfig} />
    </Switch>
  )}
</Router>
```